# how to restrict file upload size in server side?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the template file

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, [multipart: true], fn f -> %>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>csv file</label>
    <%= file_input f, :csv, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>

  <div  class="form-group">
    <%= submit "Save" , class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>
<%end %>
```

In the controller.exs file

```
  def create(conn, %{"batch" => batch_params}) do
    IO.inspect(batch_params,label: "before")
    IO.inspect(batch_params["csv"],label: "csv")
    if upload = batch_params["csv"] do
      extension = Path.extname(upload.filename)
      IO.inspect(extension,label: "file name")
      File.cp(upload.path, "/var/tmp/aaabbb")
    end
    case Imports.create_batch(batch_params) do
      {:ok, batch} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Batch created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.batch_path(conn, :show, batch))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

Because the `create` function will be called when the file is already completely uploaded, it is not suitable to restrict the file size.
Where to restrict the file size?

Comment: can't you count the bytes inside of your controller and return error in case the file is bigger than expected?

Comment: My first idea is to restrict the size in the controller, but it seems too late and it may have much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a maximum file size by configuring `:length` in [`Plug.Parsers`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html#module-examples)

> For example, to support file uploads, you can do:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers,
     parsers: [:url_encoded, :multipart],
     length: 20_000_000
```

> However, the above will increase the maximum length of all request types. If you want to increase the limit only for multipart requests (which is typically the ones used for file uploads), you can do:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers,
     parsers: [
       :url_encoded,
       {:multipart, length: 20_000_000} # Increase to 20MB max upload
     ]
```

Comment: I have modified accordingly by `length: 2_000_000` , but it still allows file of size 3.8MB and no error message.